# Python exif orientation KeyError: '274'

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, exif

When uploading and image I'm getting an internal server error. Then going to heroku logs I see this KeyError

This is my code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    if request.files['photo']:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        foo = Image.open("static/img/"+filename)
        exifimage = foo._getexif()
        if exifimage:
            for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() :
                if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation':
                    break

            exif=dict(exifimage.items())

            if exif[orientation] == 3 :
                foo=foo.rotate(180, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 6 :
                foo=foo.rotate(270, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 8 :
                foo=foo.rotate(90, expand=True)
```

This is the complete error:

```
if exif[orientation] == 3 :
KeyError: 274
```

Why could this be happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Based on that error message, what do you think is the value of `orientation` when the error occurs? Does that make sense to use as a key in `exif`? Why or why not?

Comment: @AMC This error is only happening with images downloaded from the internet, for example if you upload images from camera roll it's not returning any error

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm a bit noob with this stuff, but I know that I need this piece of code because otherwise the images will be rotated. This error happens only with images downloaded from the internet, if you upload a photo from your camera roll it will work fine

Comment: Okay, but I asked the *specific* questions I did for a *reason*. How much do you know about the exif data format in general? Where exactly do you need help? Questions like "why" are not feasible to answer in a vacuum; we need to know where you're at in order to explain things in a way useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I encountered the same problem.

It will work without error if the image file has EXIF data, otherwise there is nothing to read in and an exception is thrown. (Also, if you rotate a rectangular image 90 or 270 degrees, you'll more than likely want to flip the height and width so the canvas matches the new orientation.)

You should put in a try block:

```
try:
    exif_data = open_image.getexif()
    for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
        if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation':
            break
    print ("Rotation: " + str(exif_data[orientation]))
    if exif_data[orientation] == 3:
        open_image = open_image.rotate(180, expand=True)
    elif exif_data[orientation] == 6:
        open_image = open_image.rotate(270, expand=True)
        img_picture_width, img_picture_height = img_picture_height, img_picture_width
    elif exif_data[orientation] == 8:
        open_image = open_image.rotate(90, expand=True)
        img_picture_width, img_picture_height = img_picture_height, img_picture_width
except Exception as e:
    print ("Exif data spinning errored (might have no exif data)")
    print (e)
```